# How to use distribute classes with Apache Spark (pyspark) & Docker

Tags: python, apache-spark, docker, pyspark

I'm building a brand new data science stack for use in our work environment by data scientist and data analysts.

Basically, my structure is the following:

- CDH installed on all nodes in cluster (bare metal)
- Spark & YARN within CDH distribution
- Docker container image with multiple components: Anaconda, Python3, Spark (PySpark), Jupyter Notebook

Now, my initial though was to distribute that docker image on all worker nodes for Python dependency and also include custom libraries needed to run Spark job inside of this container (e.x.: xgboost, numpy, etc).  My workflow would be the following when doing interactive analysis in Jupyter:

1. Create Jupyter Notebook
2. Initialize SparkContext and point master to YARN
3. Run Spark job with custom Python library code

Now, I'm wondering two things:

1. How will Spark (running outside container) access my custom Python library on all worker nodes (custom code inside Docker container).
2. How do I distribute those custom librariries and other complex dependancies?  I know we can use functions like sc.addPyFile('/path/to/BoTree.py') or a complete .zip archive, but is there an easier way with Docker?  I'm not using Anaconda cluster, so I need another way to do it.

Thanks